# Fork example assistance

Tags: c, fork

I am learning about fork and I was hoping if someone could provide a parent-child relation diagram for the code provided. I already ran it in C, and got the output. Just need some confirmation with my understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int i, pid, notdone = 1;
  for (i = 0 ; i < 2 && notdone ; i++)
  {
    printf("Tic!\n");
    if ((pid=fork())==0)
    {
      printf("Tac!\n");
      notdone=0;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Toe!\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Output: Tic Toe Tic Tac Toe Tac

I believe fork gets called twice so there are 4 processes running. 1) "Tic" then fork, Parent goes first, "Toe", runs the loop again, "Tic" then fork again but first waits for Child1; "Tac" then goes back to Parent since the condition test failed, Parent goes again, "Toe", runs the loop again but fails condition so exits; Child2 goes, "Tac", exits since condition test failed. Did I get that right?

Comment: Are you working on a very old system with a very old compiler?

Comment: You can't count on the order. The parent and child run in parallel.

Comment: **main(){}** should be **int main(void){}**

Comment: I'm running it with Putty, the code compiles and works just fine

Comment: *the code compiles and works just fine* doesn't always mean 1. It's correct. 2. It will keep doing so.

Comment: ...so are you saying there are many solutions to this problem?

Comment: There are many solutions to every problem (except some mathematical problems with unique solutions) though there are many paths to the solution ALWAYS anyway. If you don't know that you should learn it.

Comment: @user3267385 I think iharob's point is that you've taken a few short-cuts with your C syntax. They're not harmful because your compiler is being lenient, but you need to at least understand that you're doing it.

Comment: @user3267385 it is not possible to "run" something with "Putty". Putty is a SSH CLIENT and does not "run" anything unless you somehow chain its execution to another executable.

Comment: @user3267385 your code will fail to compile if you compile it with c99 or c11 standard. Remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 processes: the parent, and two children.

The parent does this sequence: "Tic", `fork`, "Toe", "Tic", `fork`, "Toe", Exit.

Each child does this sequence: "Tac", Exit.

How the output happens to interleave is undefined, meaning that there are no rules that say how it *must* happen, so your "waits", and "goes back" are incorrect. In practice, you'll probably find that output order doesn't vary much on an unloaded computer, because the timings are what they are, but you should *never* rely on it.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, but I was taught that there are 2^n processes  , n being the number of times fork is called, it just "branched" again when making the children.

Comment: A call to `fork` creates *one* new fork. However, if that new process then calls `fork`, and so on, then it can go exponential. That's a fork bomb.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks again for your answer, you were the most helpful here regarding my question.